# How to add delay before going to next slide in PPT using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint, wait

The Slide Show has to be "Browsed at a Kiosk". I don't want to give the users the option to go to the next slide by pressing the next key or anything like that.

It's a quiz game. By pressing the correct option the following code activates:

```
Sub CorrectAnswer()
Correct.Caption = (Correct.Caption) + 1
Percentage.Caption = (Percentage.Caption) + 5
MsgBox "That was the correct answer!", vbInformation + vbApplicationModal, "FOLK Quiz"
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
End Sub
```

The user presses any one of the four options. There's a trigger for each box. When the trigger is activated one of the box turns green and the rest turns red. I've done this by using Animations.

Then I want to go to the next slide after a few seconds after the animation... but how is this possible?
Is there any way to add a delay in going to the next slide in VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some wait time before going to next slide. It is posible by using [`Application.Wait`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822851.aspx). Your code then will look like this:

```
Sub CorrectAnswer()

  Correct.Caption = (Correct.Caption) + 1

  Percentage.Caption = (Percentage.Caption) + 5

  MsgBox "That was the correct answer!", vbInformation + _
                                         vbApplicationModal, "FOLK Quiz"
  lag = 3 
  start = Timer

  While Timer < Start + lag
        DoEvents
  Wend


  'Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")) 'This adds 3 sec delay in ms VBA

  ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't imagine this will work, unfortunately. The PowerPoint Application object doesn't have a .Wait method. If you know the show will run under Windows and not Mac/cloud/etc, you could include a Sleep WinAPI call:  Put your macro to Sleep
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00466_Put_your_macro_to_Sleep.htm

Comment: @SteveRindsberg You're right. BUt why not `DoEvents`. I had to take a look at the documentation. I was about to but as the OP accepted didn't go for that.

Comment: DoEvents might indeed DoIt  ;-)  But you might want to edit your reply to remove the Application.Wait suggestion, since that doesn't apply to PPT.  Thx.

Comment: If I add triggers for animation in the slide, this doesn't work!
I see the message box, the +5 and +1 works. But it doesn't go to the next slide.. If I press again, it does.

I've changed the lag to 1.